# Is there a way to use csv file containing string as input to the neural network. the input csv file contains encoded number with spaces

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification

I am modelling a neural network to classify apks' as malicious and benign. The training data consist of .csv file. In the file encoded information(as numbers) are present separated by spaces (in a single record). There are multiple records. When I used this file in the code it does not give any output. I want to convert the string into float so that it can be handled by the model

Comment: There is a way. Provide the code that you have tried and example of the data you have.

Comment: A single record in .csv file has the format 
365 384 390 408 417 425 426 428 430 431 472 485 568 644 646 656 663 665 703 704 706 711 714 720 723 766 767 768 769 770 830 856 873 1477 1485 1531 1546 1624 1628 1629 1631 1636 1748 1769 1884 1891 1895 1898 1899 1903 1911 1914 1919 1944 1945 1946 1947 2120 2256 2289 2291 2293 2318 2324 2338 2340 2341 2343 2354 2358 2368 2372 2375 2430 2449 2454 2468 2473 2480 2482 2486 2494 2497 2498 2504 2507 2525 2528 2559 2908 2922 2923 3010 3012 3013 3014 3016 3018 3020 3022

Comment: In what code you've used this data? Please append the code and the data example to your question.

Comment: @Vlad i am using the dataset of android apks used in CDMC competitions. the numbers in the above comment is a row of dataset used for training and the code is shown below: x_train = pd.read_csv("CDMC2017_T1_AndroidAPITrainData.csv")
hidden_layer_1 = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(x_train[0]), n_nodes_hl1])), 'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}....l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_layer_1['weights']), hidden_layer_1['biases'])
   l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

Comment: So what is the problem. What is the output you expect this line to produce?

Comment: the problem is it take input as float and this csv file is of type string so i need to convert it into float by assigning ids or by other mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert to floats use this:

```py
x_train = pd.read_csv("CDMC2017_T1_AndroidAPITrainData.csv")
x_train = x_train.to_numpy()
x_train = np.float32(x_train)
```

Comment: thanks alot for your time and for solving this issue :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider accepting my answer (pressing on `accept this answer` button).